# make tcp server socket class for android with Delphi Xe5

Tags: android, delphi, sockets, delphi-xe5

project files on: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8cUQ4cVltbWFzYUk/edit?usp=sharing
here is the my running codes

```
    ...........
try
soket1:=TJServerSoket.JavaClass.init((8090));
//adres:=soket1.iNetAdres.ip;
memo1.Lines.Add('Port: '+inttostr(soket1.Port));
except
  on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('Port Açılamadı: '+E.Message);
end;
try
  memo1.Lines.Add('ip: '+jstringtostring((soket1.iNetAdres.Host)));
except
  on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('ip bigisi alınamadı: '+E.Message);

end;
.............

............

try
  soketC:=soket1.accept;
  //o1.writeChars(stringtojstring('merhaba'));
  memo1.Lines.Add('accept' );
except
  on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('accept Hata: '+E.Message);

end;

....................

try


  //i1:=soketC.getInputStream;
  memo1.Lines.Add('i1: '+inttostr(soketC.getInputStream.read) );
  //memo1.Lines.Add('i1: '+jstringtostring(soketC.getInputStream.readUTF) );
except
  on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('i1 Hata: '+E.Message);
end;

try
  //o1:=TJoutStream.JavaClass.init(soketC.getOutputStream);
  //o1.writeChars(stringtojstring('merhaba') );
  soketC.getOutputStream.write(65);
  memo1.Lines.Add('o1: merhaba' );
except
  on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('o1 Hata: '+E.Message);
end;

//soketC.getOutputStream.close;
//soketC.getInputStream.close;
//soketC.close;
```

please help...
i'm trying "write" / "read" (inputstream/outputstream) to socket but i get error...

here is the my bad socket (socket' "s" ) api:

```
.............
.............

  ////////////////////////////soket/////////////////////////////


  [javaSignature('java/net/InetAddress')]
  JAdres=interface(JObject)
  ['{7A525333-38BC-4D2A-8160-D164D1CAA30E}']
    function getHostName:Jstring;cdecl;

    property Host:Jstring read getHostName;

  end;

  JAdresClass=interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{B34C47C9-7FC8-4120-B087-60F517A9323D}']

  end;

  TJAdres = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAdresClass, JAdres>) end;


 ////////////////out buffer////////////////////
 ///

     [javaSignature('java/io/OutputStream')]
  Jout=interface(jobject)
    ['{AC9EEC99-FF3A-46E4-AFC3-C4D3309D8C8E}']
    //procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;//overload;
    //property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    procedure write(buffer:array of integer;offset,count:integer);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:array of integer);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:integer);cdecl;overload; //tek bit yaz
    //procedure writeChars(str:jstring);cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure flush;cdecl;
  end;
  JoutClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{46FBBEEE-22C7-45EA-BED3-A41BED01E500}']
    procedure init(); cdecl;//Deprecated
    end;

  TJout = class(TJavaGenericImport<JoutClass, Jout>) end;

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    [javaSignature('java/io/ObjectOutputStream')]
  JoutStream=interface(jobject)
    ['{A6421CC3-B76C-4124-AB2E-AEE0C4749E71}']
    //procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;//overload;
    //property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    procedure write(buffer:array of integer;offset,count:integer);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:array of integer);cdecl;overload;
    procedure write(buffer:integer);cdecl;overload; //tek bit yaz
    procedure writeChars(str:jstring);cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure flush;cdecl;
  end;
  JoutStreamClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{83D69F8F-8833-4EF5-B00D-2EA45F58AC46}']
    function init(obj:Jout):JoutStream; cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
    end;

  TJoutStream = class(TJavaGenericImport<JoutStreamClass, JoutStream>) end;
  ///////////////////////input buffer/////////////////

       [javaSignature('java/io/InputStream')]
  Jin=interface(jobject)
   ['{42549EE4-B69C-4491-BEC1-5626C4E7D717}']
    //procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;//overload;
    //property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    function read(buffer:array of jbyte;offset,count:integer):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read(buffer:array of jbyte):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read():integer;cdecl;overload; //tek bit yaz
    //function readUTF():jstring;cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure reset;cdecl;
  end;
  JinClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{AA965CF8-ED96-4EFE-B5F3-B02DAEDA8979}']
    function init():Jin; cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
    //procedure init(); cdecl;overload;
    end;

  TJin = class(TJavaGenericImport<JinClass, Jin>) end;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     [javaSignature('java/io/ObjectInputStream')]
  JinStream=interface(jobject)
   ['{839ACAEC-229A-4261-88B4-136173B6FCBF}']
    //procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;//overload;
    //property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    function read(buffer:array of jbyte;offset,count:integer):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read(buffer:array of jbyte):integer;cdecl;overload;
    function read():integer;cdecl;overload; //tek bit yaz
    function readUTF():jstring;cdecl;
    procedure close;cdecl;
    procedure reset;cdecl;
  end;
  JinStreamClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{27B4071A-5BC8-4594-A701-DBB92DBEE45A}']
    procedure init(); cdecl;overload; Deprecated;
    //procedure init(); cdecl;overload;
    end;

  TJinStream = class(TJavaGenericImport<JinStreamClass, JinStream>) end;




 ////////////////client socket////////////////////
  [javaSignature('java/net/Socket')]
  JSoket=interface(jobject)
   ['{3120C92A-DA6B-4584-B6FB-DEDEB36CA6FB}']
      procedure close;cdecl;
      function getOutputStream:Jout;cdecl;
      function getInputStream:Jin;cdecl;


  end;

    JSoketClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{F1C713D1-9A17-48EF-BD98-60FD859A2B3E}']
    function init:JSoket; //cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
  end;

  TJSoket = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSoketClass, JSoket>) end;

///

  [javaSignature('java/net/ServerSocket')]
  JServerSoket=interface(jobject)
    ['{FB896B05-0F70-4BF7-A69D-4655D173A303}']
    function getLocalPort:integer;cdecl;//overload;
    procedure bind(localAddr:integer);cdecl;//overload;
    procedure close;cdecl;//overload;
    function getInetAddress:JAdres;cdecl;
    function accept():JSoket;cdecl;

    property Port: Integer read getLocalPort;
    property iNetAdres: JAdres read getInetAddress;
    //function getLocalPort: Integer; cdecl;
    //procedure ServerSocket(port:integer);cdecl;

  end;

    JServerSoketClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{5D578C73-1315-4143-B14C-8E26BC1975BC}']
    function init(port:integer):JServerSoket; //cdecl;overload;//Deprecated
  end;

  TJServerSoket = class(TJavaGenericImport<JServerSoketClass, JServerSoket>) end;

..........
```

Comment: Do you think it might be useful to tell us what error you get?

Comment: application freezes and segmentation fault

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the Indy `TIdTCPServer` component instead, which has all of the functionality written for you? It supports all platforms XE5 does, including Android.

Comment: :) no. indy client components ok, but server components are gets no run or segmentation error.

Comment: The server components work fine. It might be better to ask a question about Indy and show the code you had problems with; Remy LeBeau (one of the maintainers of Indy) is a frequent visitor here, and is quite good at spotting errors (and even fixing bugs quickly) based on code from questions here. It would seem a lot better than what you're trying now (IMO). :-)

Comment: and this code is can open a port and return port number, native. but problem is write a bit or read with java.io.ObjectOutputStream or java.io.ObjectInputStream

Comment: indy servers components (for android) problem point:
TIdIOHandler.Write
indy

Comment: @ilhangöksel: if you are having a particular problem using Indy, post a new question asking about it, with code showing the problem. Indy uses the native POSIX socket API on Android (which has a Linux core) so performance is bound to be better than using JNI to access the Java socket API (BTW, Delphi open arrays are not compatible with Java arrays, but your JNI declarations are not accounting for that).

Comment: @RemyLebeau : thnx you very much.
So, can you show me a "working indy server example app on android", with delphi-xe5 ?

Comment: Have you looked at any existing Indy demos/examples yet? Indy works the same on all platforms.

Comment: sure, i was. can you write a document or example for about indy server socket for android with delphi xe5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need fix;

```
[javaSignature('java/io/OutputStream')]
Jout=interface(jobject)
['{AC9EEC99-FF3A-46E4-AFC3-C4D3309D8C8E}']
procedure write(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>;offset,count:integer);cdecl;overload;
procedure write(buffer:TJavaArray<byte>);cdecl;overload;
...........
```

write buffer;

encoded (for ı ş İ ç ö ğ ...) function;

```
function stringtoJbyte(metin:String):TJavaArray<byte>;
var
  buffer: TJavaArray<byte>;
  bufferByte:TArray<byte>;
  i,len:integer;
begin
  bufferByte:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metin);
  //len:=ByteLength(metin);
  len:=length(bufferByte);
  buffer := TJavaArray<byte>.Create(len+1);
  for i := 0 to len do
        buffer.Items[i+1]:=bufferByte[i] ;
  result:=buffer;
end;
```

call api func;

```
soketC.getOutputStream.write(stringtoJbyte('kesinlikle yazar'));
```

Comment: project files here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8cUQ4cVltbWFzYUk/edit?usp=sharing
the and.