# how can i convert byte to JByte in delphi xe5?

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, delphi-xe5

have jstringtostring or stringtojstring.
how can i convert byte to JByte (or other variables types)?

```
....
var x:jbyte;
begin
 x:=bytetojbyte(65);
....
end;
```

thanks.

Comment: at procedure write(buffer:jbyte);cdecl;overload;.... for [javaSignature('java.io.OutputStream')].

Comment: yes i have seen. but i get "access violation at address ....." on byteX:=TJByte.JavaClass.init(65); Is there an easier way of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.io.OutputStream.write()` expects a `byte[]` (ie, an array of bytes) as input. Delphi's `JByte` interface is a JNI wrapper for the `java.lang.Byte` class, which is itself a Java object wrapper for a single `byte` value.  `JByte` does not represent an array of bytes, so you cannot use `JByte` with `OutputStream.write()`.

If you look at the declaration of Delphi's `JOutputStream` interface (the JNI wrapper for `java.io.OutputStream`) in the `Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes` unit, it has `write()` methods that expect `TJavaArray<Byte>` as input. `TJavaArray<T>` is declared in the `Androidapi.JNIBridge` unit.  If you are trying to pass a data buffer from your Delphi code to `OutputStream.write()`, you will have to declare a `TJavaArray<Byte>` variable, allocate it to the desired length, and copy your data into it, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

var
  buffer: TJavaArray<Byte>;
begin
  buffer := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(DesiredLength);
  Move(SourceByteData^, buffer.Data^, DesiredLength);
  SomeOutputStream.write(buffer);
end;
```

Comment: really thanks you! i think you are best.. my socket was wrote the first "A" char :D . ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276318/make-tcp-server-socket-class-for-android-with-delphi-xe5#comment30272747_20276318 )

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringtoJbyte(metin:string):TJavaArray<Byte>;
var
  buffer: TJavaArray<Byte>;
  i:integer;
begin
  buffer := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(length(metin)+1);
  for i := 1 to Length(metin) do
        buffer.Items[i]:= ord( (metin[i-1]) );
  result:=buffer;
end;
```

I use this code! it work for me.
thanks again remy lebeau..

encoded (for ı ş İ ç ö ğ ...) function;

```
function stringtoJbyte(metin:String):TJavaArray<byte>;
var
  buffer: TJavaArray<byte>;
  bufferByte:TArray<byte>;
  i,len:integer;
begin
  bufferByte:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metin);
  //len:=ByteLength(metin);
  len:=length(bufferByte);
  buffer := TJavaArray<byte>.Create(len+1);
  for i := 0 to len do
        buffer.Items[i+1]:=bufferByte[i] ;
  result:=buffer;
end;
```

Comment: Your code is not handling non-ASCII Unicode characters. Also, Java arrays are 0-indexed, same as Delphi strings on mobile compilers (but they are still 1-indexed on desktop compilers). You should convert the `string` to a `Byte` array via `TEncoding.GetBytes()` (or equivalent), then copy those bytes into the Java array using `Move()` instead of a manual loop.

Comment: You need to replace `len:=ByteLength(metin)` with `len:=Length(bufferByte)` instead. And why are you allocating `+1`? Again, Java arrays are 0-indexed, not 1-indexed. `buffer := TJavaArray<byte>.Create(len); ... buffer.Items[i] := ...`. Better, just get rid of the loop altogether: `buffer := TJavaArray<byte>.Create(len); if len > 0 then Move(PByte(bufferByte)^, buffer.Data^, len);`

Comment: worked project files here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxODt2IJsmR8cUQ4cVltbWFzYUk/edit?usp=sharing
if you look it.. (very buggy, but read and write OK!)